# Using JDBI Mapper Annotation with Constructor in Dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard, jdbi

I am using Dropwizard 1.0.0 along with JDBI 2.73.
I want to create a mapper with some objects. Hence, a constructor with some arguments.

But it is throwing exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.xyz.db.ReportMapper.<init>()
```

DAO is created

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM reports")
@Mapper(ReportMapper.class)
List<Report> findReports();
```

Mapper is created.

```
public class ReportMapper implements ResultSetMapper<Report> {
    private static final String ID_COLUMN = "id";
    private static final String NAME_COLUMN = "name";
    private static final String START_DATE_COLUMN = "start_date";
    private static final String END_DATE_COLUMN = "end_date";

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ReportMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper){
        this.mapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Report map(int index, ResultSet resultSet, StatementContext statementContext) throws SQLException {

        return Report.builder()
            .id(resultSet.getInt(ID_COLUMN))
            .name(resultSet.getString(NAME_COLUMN))
            .startDate(resultSet.getDate(START_DATE_COLUMN))
            .endDate(resultSet.getDate(END_DATE_COLUMN))
            .build();
    }
```

How can a mapper with constructor be created and used as annotation?

Comment: can you post your full ReportMapper class ?

Comment: @Manikandan I have updated the Mapper class code

Answer (score 4):

As Manikandan suggests, when using `@Mapper` the class must have a no-arg constructor.

However, you can register a `ResultSetMapper` yourself without this restriction, e.g.:

```
dbi.registerMapper(new ReportMapper(new ObjectMapper()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Mappers should have one no args constructor. Since objectMapper is not used, I removed it. The below mapper should work fine.

```
public class ReportMapper implements ResultSetMapper<Report> {
  private static final String ID_COLUMN = "id";
  private static final String NAME_COLUMN = "name";
  private static final String START_DATE_COLUMN = "start_date";
  private static final String END_DATE_COLUMN = "end_date";

  @Override
  public Report map(int index, ResultSet resultSet, StatementContext statementContext) throws SQLException {

    return Report.builder()
        .id(resultSet.getInt(ID_COLUMN))
        .name(resultSet.getString(NAME_COLUMN))
        .startDate(resultSet.getDate(START_DATE_COLUMN))
        .endDate(resultSet.getDate(END_DATE_COLUMN))
        .build();
  }
}
```

Comment: I will be using the ObjectMapper. I may need to pass more objects.

Comment: If you need to inject objects from outside JDBI into your mapper, then Jonathan's answer should do the trick.